# Tabs page not visible when entering url from outside app in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic - angular application, where I created a separte tabs page as follows:

**tabs.ts**

```
// all imports are made

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class MyTabs {

  tab1Root = 'AlarmPage'; // made ionic page. so deeplink is already created.
  tab2Root = 'FormsPage'; // same as above comment.


  constructor() {

  }
}
```

**tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="AlarmPage" tabIcon="alarm"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="FormsPage" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

**AlarmPage.ts**

```
// all imports are done
// Its an ionic page with deeplink

@IonicPage({
   segment: alarm/:id
 })
```

The url for alarm page is `http://localhost:8100/#/tab-0/alarm/5aba3`.

**Issue:** When navigatng this page from inside the app i.e from other pages the tabs page is visibe at the bottom, but when pasting this url in the browser's address bar the alarm page is visible with the same url but the Tabs page is not visible.

I want to make visible the Tabs page when accessing this page outside the app i.e pasting the url in the address bar of the browser.

Also when I refresh the page I can see the tabs for some time and then again the tabs become invisible.

Comment: I solve one issue in another post but you don't give me helpful flag or not give one vote for supporting..

Comment: right now I have voted your answer, to accept it have to first check whether it has fulfilled to my requirements, I will accept it sooner.